# How to include interactions of factors with h2o.interaction and h2o.glm in R h2o package

Tags: r, h2o

I wish to fit a logistic regression with `h2o.glm` including some interactions between factors.  However, simple usage of `h2o.interaction` followed by `h2o.glm` ends up including too many dummy variables in the regression.  Here is a reproducible example.

```
# model.matrix function in R returns a matrix 
# with the intercept, 1 dummy for Age, 1 dummy for Sex, and 1 dummy for Age:Sex
colnames(model.matrix(Survived ~ Age + Sex + Age:Sex, data = Titanic))
[1] "(Intercept)"        "AgeAdult"           "SexFemale"          "AgeAdult:SexFemale"

# create an H2OFrame with the interaction of Age and Sex as a factor
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
Titanic.hex <- as.h2o(Titanic)
interact.hex <- h2o.cbind(Titanic.hex[,c("Survived","Age","Sex")]
                          ,h2o.interaction(Titanic.hex
                          ,factors = list(c("Age", "Sex"))
                          ,pairwise = T
                          ,max_factors = 99
                          ,min_occurrence = 1))

# Age_Sex interaction column has 4 levels
h2o.levels(interact.hex$Age_Sex)
[1] "Child_Male"   "Child_Female" "Adult_Male"   "Adult_Female"

# Because Age_Sex interaction column has 4 levels 
# we end up with 3 dummies to represent Age:Sex
interact.h2o.glm <- h2o.glm(2:ncol(interact.hex)
                            ,"Survived"
                            ,interact.hex
                            ,family = 'binomial'
                            ,lambda = 0)
h2o.varimp(interact.h2o.glm)$names
[1] "Age_Sex.Child_Female" "Age_Sex.Adult_Male"   "Age_Sex.Adult_Female" "Sex.Male"            
[5] "Age.Child"            ""
```

What is a good way to do interactions between factors with h2o such that the `h2o.glm` behaves like `model.matrix`?  In the example above, I would like to see only 1 dummy variable for the interaction between `Age` and `Sex` instead of 3 dummy variables.

Answer (score 0):

Background: What you are seeing is one-hot encoding: a linear model can only deal with numbers, not categories. (Deep learning too.) So, it makes a boolean variable for each category (i.e. each factor level). E.g. gender_male will be 1 if they are male, 0 otherwise, while gender_female will be 1 if they are female, 0 otherwise. When you add interactions, you are seeing is a boolean for each possible combination of the categories.

H2O's deep learning algorithm has `use_all_factor_levels` as an argument, which defaults to true. If you set it to false then one of the factors will be done implicitly. For two-level factors that means you will get just a single column, e.g. 0 for male, 1 for female. This would give you the reduced fields you were expecting.

Unfortunately `h2o.glm()` doesn't have that option at the moment, and neither does `h2o.interaction()` as far as a I can see.

You could simulate it yourself by using `h2o.ifelse()`, with `h2o.cbind()`. E.g.

```
interact.hex <- h2o.cbind(
  Titanic.hex[,c("Class","Survived")],
  h2o.ifelse(Titanic.hex$Age == "Adult", 1, 0),
  h2o.ifelse(Titanic.hex$Sex == "Female", 1, 0)
  )
interact.hex <- h2o.cbind(
  interact.hex,
  h2o.ifelse(interact.hex$C1 == 1 && interact.hex$C10 == 1, 1, 0)
)
```

But that is a bit tedious, isn't it, and the columns could do with renaming afterwards.

Comment: I have also added my workaround as a separate answer.  h2o.glm can handle factors automatically, but I have to do a workaround so that essentially 0*0 = 1*0 = 0*1 = 0.  My workaround collapses 3 levels 0*0, 1*0, 0*1 into a single level.

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp I think you'll find the above code more efficient (and giving the same values?),  as I've only used H2O built-in functions. If I've understood your solution correctly it is "Have H2O make the wrong data, then fix it in R code"?

Comment: My solution actually only uses R code to make the level1 character vector and then applies h2o.ifelse to fix the data (I've updated my ifelse to be h2o.ifelse to make this more clear).  It by no means passes the full data from h2o back to R.  It's also preferable for me as my real data (not posted here) has some factors with lots of categories.  In my workaround I only need to specify the factor and rather than the specific levels.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my own workaround here that does what I want.  However, I'd still be happy to see a more elegant or built-in answer here.

```
# create H2OFrame and interact as in the question
Titanic.hex <- as.h2o(Titanic)
interact.hex <- h2o.cbind(Titanic.hex[,c("Survived","Age","Sex")]
                          ,h2o.interaction(Titanic.hex
                          ,factors = list(c("Age", "Sex"))
                          ,pairwise = T
                          ,max_factors = 99
                          ,min_occurrence = 1))

# Define a function that collapses interaction levels
collapse_level1_interacts <- function(df, column, col1, col2){
  level1 <- rbind(
    data.table::CJ(h2o.levels(df[,col1])[1], h2o.levels(df[,col2]))
    ,data.table::CJ(h2o.levels(df[,col1]), h2o.levels(df[,col2])[1]))
    level1 <- paste(level1$V1, level1$V2, sep='_')
    df[,column] <- h2o.ifelse(df[,column] %in% level1, '00000', df[,column])
    return(df)
}

# Run the H2oFrame through the function
interact.hex2 <- collapse_level1_interacts(interact.hex, "Age_Sex", "Age", "Sex")

# Verify that we have only 2 levels for interaction
h2o.levels(interact.hex2$Age_Sex)
[1] "00000"      "Child_Male"

# Verify that we have only 1 dummy for the interaction
interact.h2o.glm <- h2o.glm(2:ncol(interact.hex2)
                            ,"Survived"
                            ,interact.hex2
                            ,family = 'binomial'
                            ,lambda = 0)
h2o.varimp(interact.h2o.glm)$names
[1] "Age.Child"          "Sex.Male"           "Age_Sex.Child_Male" ""
```